# Qt5 Delete the suffix of a filepath

Tags: c++, qt5, chop, lastindexof

I'm trying to figure out the QString::lastIndexOf and QString::chop to delete a suffix off a file, so I can add one myself. However, I get weird output that doesn't make sense to me.

Here's my test code:

```
QString filename = "C:/Users/Ir77/Desktop/a.png";
qDebug() << "Filename is " << filename;
QString y = '.';
int x = filename.lastIndexOf(y, -1);
qDebug() << "Last index of . is " << x;
filename.chop(x);
qDebug() << "filename is now " << filename;
```

And here's the qDebug() info that I get from it:

```
Filename is  "C:/Users/Ir77/Desktop/a.png" 
Last index of . is  23 
filename is now  "C:/U"
```

I'm trying to only make it delete the ".png" at the end. I have no idea where the 23 comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QString::chop() removes characters from the end of the string. "." is the 23rd (0-based) char, but calling chop() removes 23 characters and leaves you with "C:/U".

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstring.html#chop

Had you considered using QFileInfo so that it does the work for you? (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html) That'll give you a bunch of handy functions to get paths, portions of the filename, etc.

(I'm more familiar with Qt 4.8, but I'm assuming chop() hasn't changed in Qt 5.0.)

Comment: Yeah! Thanks allot. I didn't realize that the .lastIndexOf counts the QString from the start! And yeah, I ended up using QFileInfo as well!